# Confused about calling a method from another class

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to implement a DiceThrowingGame which works fine. I have 2 classes currently which are **"Player"** and **"Game"**. The code for the Game class is as below:

package dice.throwing.game;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Game {
    private int winningPoints;
    private Player player1, player2;
    private boolean gameSetup;

    private final String defaultWinningScore = "200";

    public Game() {
        this.setWinningPoints(200);
        this.gameSetup = false;
    }

    private int readScore(Scanner scanner) {
        String score = "";
        try {
            score = scanner.nextLine();
            if (score.isEmpty()) {
                score = this.defaultWinningScore;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(score);
    }

    private Player createPlayer(Scanner scanner) {
        String name = null;
        do {
            try {
                name = scanner.nextLine();
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.println("Name cannot be empty. Try again: ");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } while (name.isEmpty());

        return new Player(name);
    }

    private void startGame(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Enter first player's name: ");
        player1 = createPlayer(scanner);
        System.out.println("Enter second player's name: ");
        player2 = createPlayer(scanner);
        System.out.println("Maximum score to win (<Enter> to use default 200): ");
        this.setWinningPoints(this.readScore(scanner));
        this.gameSetup = true;
    }

    private void playOneRound() {
        int p1r1, p1r2, p2r1, p2r2;
        p1r1 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
        p1r2 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
        p2r1 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
        p2r2 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));

        int p1Points, p2Points;
        boolean p1Bonus = false, p2Bonus = false;
        p1Points = p1r1 + p1r2;
        p2Points = p2r1 + p2r2;
        if (p1r1 == p1r2) {
            p1Points *= 2;
            p1Bonus = true;
        }
        if (p2r1 == p2r2) {
            p2Points *= 2;
            p2Bonus = true;
        }

        player1.setTotalPoints(player1.getTotalPoints() + p1Points);
        player2.setTotalPoints(player2.getTotalPoints() + p2Points);
        System.out.print(player1.getName() + " rolled " + p1r1 + " + " + p1r2 + ", and scored " + p1Points + " points");
        if (p1Bonus)
            System.out.println(" (BONUS!)");
        else
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print(player2.getName() + " rolled " + p2r1 + " + " + p2r2 + ", and scored " + p2Points + " points");
        if (p2Bonus)
            System.out.println(" (BONUS!)");
        else
            System.out.println();
    }

    private void leaderBoard() {
        int p1Points = player1.getTotalPoints();
        int p2Points = player2.getTotalPoints();

        if (p1Points == p2Points)
            System.out.println("Both players have the same score (" + p1Points + ") at the moment");
        else {
            System.out.print(player1.getName() + "'s current score is " + p1Points);
            if (p1Points > p2Points)
                System.out.println(" <--- CURRENT LEADER!");
            else
                System.out.println();
            System.out.print(player2.getName() + "'s current score is " + p2Points);
            if (p1Points < p2Points)
                System.out.println(" <--- CURRENT LEADER!");
            else
                System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private void gameHelp() {
        System.out.println("<ENTER SOME HELP TEXT HERE>");
    }

    private boolean isGameOver() {
        int player1Points = player1.getTotalPoints();
        int player2Points = player2.getTotalPoints();

        if(player1Points == player2Points &&
                player1Points > this.winningPoints) {
            System.out.println("Game Over! It's a draw!");
            return true;
        } else if(player1Points > this.winningPoints && player1Points > player2Points) {
            System.out.println("Game Over! " + player1.getName() + " is the winner!");
            return true;
        } else if(player2Points > this.winningPoints && player2Points > player1Points) {
            System.out.println("Game Over! " + player2.getName() + " is the winner!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void eventLoop() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to my Dice-and-Roll Game!");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            System.out.println("(1) Start a new game");
            System.out.println("(2) Play one round");
            System.out.println("(3) Who is leading now?");
            System.out.println("(4) Display Game Help");
            System.out.println("(5) Exit Game");
            System.out.println("Choose an option: ");

            try {
                choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                if (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
                    System.err.println("Error : Choose an option between 1 and 5");
                    choice = 0;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Error : Choose an option between 1 and 5");
                choice = 0;
            }

            if (!this.gameSetup && (choice == 2 || choice == 3)) {
                System.err.println("Error : Players have not been setup");
                choice = 0;
            }

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                this.startGame(scanner);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.playOneRound();
                break;
            case 3:
                this.leaderBoard();
                break;
            case 4:
                this.gameHelp();
                break;
            case 5:
                exit = true;
            }

            if(this.gameSetup && this.isGameOver()) {
                System.out.println("Exiting now.. See you later!");
                exit = true;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.eventLoop();

    }

    public int getWinningPoints() {
        return winningPoints;
    }

    public void setWinningPoints(int winningPoints) {
        this.winningPoints = winningPoints;
    }

}
```

But I want to move the DiceThrowing part of the code to another class called "Dice" which is this part:

```
 private void playOneRound() {
        int p1r1, p1r2, p2r1, p2r2;
        p1r1 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
        p1r2 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
        p2r1 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
        p2r2 = (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
```

Confused on whether to put the whole playOneRound() method or just the Math.Random line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep responsibilities and abstractions separate:
I would have a method `Dice.getNumber()` which would return the result of 
`(int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));`
You could also have a 2nd method that would return an array of dice throws with a nbOfThrows parameter.

Then the playOneRound() would involve the throw of the dice as many times as the games rules allow.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I created a new class called DiceThrow with the code:
`public class DiceThrow
{
    public int generate() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return (int) (1 + ((Math.random() * 10) % 6));
    }
}`
Replaced the original code in the game class with the generate() method. Works fine now.

Comment: You should also make the Random variable an instance variable of Dice and just reuse it in generate()